# The best way to create a preference matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, recommendation-engine

I have a matrix of 193,000 users and 16,000 movies. In addition, I have a matrix of those users' interactions with movies.  [Interactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge4FD.png)

I want to create a preference matrix. If the user interacted with the movie, then on their intersection in the matrix put a score.

The interaction matrix contains 5000000 rows.

What is the best way to fill out the preference matrix?

Not what i did.
[idid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgLLd.png)

Preference matrix: `d = pd.DataFrame(0, index = submission['user_id'].unique(), columns = interactions['item_id'].unique(), dtype = 'int8')`
[matrix screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1l4f.png)

Comment: please provide a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You need  a sparse data structure  : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html

Comment: As @mozway said, please avoid posting images of code as they can't be searched or copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
df['has_watched'] = (df['watched_pct'] > 0).astype(int)
df.pivot(index='user_id',columns='item_id',values='has_watched').fillna(0)
```